# Installing MySQL using CHEF

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, cookbook

I am installing MySQL on Red hat linux system using chef.
I am following this reference of official chef site: https://learn.chef.io/manage-a-web-app/rhel/configure-mysql/

At the end I am getting this error:

> CHEF::Exception::Package: No version specified, and no candidate version available for mysql

Comment: @Drew i am new to chef and Linux, are you asking for yum cookbook or red hat Package manager? i am using MySQL cookbook for chef super market and its dependencies.

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql/issues/234? It seems like they have similiar problem.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct version of the mysql cookbook.

Comment: @coderanger, i am using latest version from chef supermarket.

Comment: The latest version doesn't use the `mysql` package on RHEL.